# XML Entity in setAttribute/addAttribute

Tags: php, xml, dom, entity, simplexml

Alright, perhaps I'm missing something simple. I've been searching for quite some time and have had no luck. I need to insert an entity into an XML attribute. In order to do this I need to be able to use an ampersand(&) in conjunction with the `setAttribute` method for the DOM class (or `addAttribute` for the `simpleXML` class). When I try to use it, it escapes the ampersand so `&entity;` becomes `&amp;entity;`. Trying to manually escape the ampersand `\&entity;` just results in `\&amp;entity;`. Typing out the ampersand entity `&amp;entity;` just doubles it `&amp;amp;entity;`. I understand why it does this, ampersands will break XML if not associated with a valid entity. The problem is, it is associated with an entity, and I can't figure out how to use it.

I've found the [createEntityReference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createentityreference.php) and [DOMEntityReference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domentityreference.construct.php) methods, but the Documentation for these methods are poor and I'm unsure if these are what I need. Googling these terms only seem to bring up the same PHP documentation, but from different sites. I've tried searching for this problem separately but I just get results explaining what I already know and pointed out above. I've tried both DOM and SimpleXML, but both produce the same results. Am I just overcomplicating this, or is this really not supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankly saying, for me it was a challenging question, since I have not thought of it myself, though the answer is rather simple:

According to even [Level 1 of the DOM recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-DOM-Level-1-19981001/level-one-core.html#ID-637646024) interface `Attr` inherits the `Node` interface, that is you can append nodes to an attribute. And `EntityReference` is allowed in `Attr` children.

> In XML, where the value of an attribute can contain entity references, the child nodes of the Attr node provide a representation in which entity references are not expanded. These child nodes may be either Text or EntityReference nodes. Because the attribute type may be unknown, there are no tokenized attribute values.

Here is a working sample in PHP:

```
<?php

// a valid XML should contain used entities declarations to be valid,
// but DOM recs do not contain means to generate DTD;
// in PHP you can use XMLWriter for the purpose though 
$dtd = <<<DTD
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE root [
  <!ENTITY my_entity "some content">
]>
<root/>
DTD;

$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->formatOutput = true;

$xml->loadXML($dtd);

$root = $xml->documentElement;

$entity = $xml->createEntityReference( 'my_entity' );

$an_attr = $xml->createAttribute( 'attr' );
$an_attr->appendChild( $xml->createTextNode('prefix ') );
$an_attr->appendChild( $entity );
$an_attr->appendChild( $xml->createTextNode(' suffix') );
$root->setAttributeNode( $an_attr );

// clone the entity to use it more than once
$root->appendChild( $entity->cloneNode() );

print $xml->saveXML();

?>
```

which results in

```
C:\>\php\5.3.8\php.exe entities.php
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE root [
<!ENTITY my_entity "some content">
]>
<root attr="prefix &my_entity; suffix">&my_entity;</root>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you. You solved a problem that has been frustrating me for days. I'll point out, if anyone else stumbles upon this, that you need to re-create the entity reference and attributenode after you append it if you wish to use it again.

Comment: @showerhead, instead of recreation you can clone the node. Besides, my example produced invalid XML (lacking entity declaration). I updated the example to reflect the issues.  I do not mind adding this into docs, thank you.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't thought about clone. On a minor note, DOM has limited DTD interaction. It cannot create it like XMLWriter, but it can reference it via [DOMImplementation::createDocumentType](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domimplementation.createdocumenttype.php).